# iphone delegate protocol can't save object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

ok, i was trying to understand this [post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html) about best way to transfer data from one view controller to other.

the thing is, if i want to set an attr of the object its works like a champ. If i try to set the entire object, it doesnt do it.

my code is:

```
@protocol AppDelegateProtocol

   - (Lote*) theLoteAppObject;

@end
```

on AppDelegate:

```
@interface AgroferiaAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, AppDelegateProtocol> {
Lote *theLoteAppObject;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Lote *theLoteAppObject;

@end
...
...
- (id) init;
{
self.theLoteAppObject = [[Lote alloc] init];
[theLoteAppObject release];
return [super init];
}
```

the class where i get the problem (UIViewcontroller):

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *) aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPax{

...

NSArray *lotes = [[self.evento lotesStore]allLotes] ; 

Lote* theDataObject = [self theLoteAppObject];

theDataObject._id = [[lotes objectAtIndex:[indexPax row]]_id];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:lotesOpViewController animated:YES];

 }
 - (Lote*) theLoteAppObject;{
id<AppDelegateProtocol> theDelegate = (id<AppDelegateProtocol>) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
Lote* theDataObject;
theDataObject = (Lote*) theDelegate.theLoteAppObject;
return theDataObject;
  }
```

so that works, but if i want to do the followimg,

```
 theDataObject = [lotes objectAtIndex:[indexPax row]];
```

it does not save the object on theDataObject.

is this a problem of bad memory managment?

edit: is it theDataObject a reference from appDelegate ?? or here is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing all the Lote items in your array are autoreleased.  Check to see if the object returned by your `[lotes objectAtIndex:[indexPax row]];` is a valid Lote object and if it is, then do a `copy` of it.

Comment: atm of doing objectAtIndex i can see that the object is there and with all his info. So u suggest that i have to make a copy of him. newby question, best way to do that in this situation?

Comment: want to add, is it ok if i create a method initWithLote:(Lote *) copyLote in the Lote class where i make a deep copy if all his attr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
if([indexPax row] < [lotes count])
{
    Lotes * dataObjectToCopy = [lotes objectAtIndex: [indexPax row]];
    if(dataObjectToCopy)
    {
        theDataObject = [dataObjectToCopy copy];
    }
}
```

This creates a separate, retained copy of your `Lote` object.  Make sure to release it when you're finished with it (if you're not using ARC).

Comment: ARC is [automated reference counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).  I've modified my original answer to show some more foolproof code.  If you're still seeing a "copyWithZone" unrecognized selector error, then it may be something else going wrong.

Comment: i did the copy, but when im looking for that object on delegate i get nil so is not being set to the appDelegate :S after theDataObject._id = [[lotes objectAtIndex:[indexPax row]]_id]; i dont need to do anything else? with that i set the object for the appDelegate and for the entire applicaiton??

Comment: Michael, doesn't he need to conform to `NSCopying` and implement `copyWithZone:`?

Comment: bleh... you are right.  `Lotes` doesn't necessarily have a way to duplicate itself.  I'd say doing the `initWithLote: (Lote *)` idea would be a good substitute for a `copy`.

Comment: ok but can some one explain me this behavior? cuz i cant follow it. when i call theDataObject = [lotes objectAtIndex:[indexPax row]]; the object theDataObject is correct and its comes previously from Lote* theDataObject = [self theLoteAppObject]; so its a reference from the object of appDelegate right?? why when i go to other class to get the same object i get nil!? 
i dont have autorelease (at least didnt find it) and dealloc is not colled :(